# Difference between official node image & other node image

Tags: node.js, docker

After dockerizing my app follows [Dockerizing a Node.js web app](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/nodejs_web_app/), I have an issue that node version on my container is 0.10.x, but I need 5.0.0, so I changed it to [official node container](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). So what are the differences between these images ?

Comment: Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the official Node.js Docker Image. One of the many benefits of using the official image is allways up to date with Node.js versions, it follows Docker's best practices, it is slimmer / smaller file size, and we provide support for Node.js Docker applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the difference in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/444da1d3492d12d1e174b2764b7c06105c0e407a/5.1/Dockerfile) of the official node image. Compared to the other [example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/nodejs_web_app/) there is essentially only the base image different (Debian vs. CentOS).

When using the [node:5-onbuild](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/444da1d3492d12d1e174b2764b7c06105c0e407a/5.1/onbuild/Dockerfile) image you also get the same layer caching technique by first adding only the package.json, followed by `npm install` and finally adding the complete project sources.

That said, I'd suggest to stick with the official images, because they are more likely to be updated regarding security issues or other image optimisations.